# Linux environment variable set but not used

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have added a new environment variable in `/etc/environment`, which now looks like this

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
  MYVAR_HOME=/include/var
```

This variable does not appear when listing all env variables with `env`. Nor it is printed when I 'echo' it

```
$ echo $MYVAR_HOME

$
```

did I miss some steps in adding it?

Comment: Have you relogged? Note this file is read when you log in.

Comment: Or at least invoke a new subshell by running "bash" or whatever shell and see if it reads the new environment that way.

Comment: You might be missing an export. Try export MYVAR_HOME=/include/var

Comment: I first exported, then logged out and logged in, and it is there now. Kind of easy! thanks

Comment: But for your user-specific environment for interactive shells, consider editing `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `/etc/environment` is not a file which is loaded upon shell initialization. Usually a POSIX compatible shell upon startup with login loads its own configuration file usually named `/etc/<shell-name>rc` (I.e. `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/zshrc` and so on), profile settings (`/etc/profile`) and corresponding files from user's home directory.

Loading /etc/profile may cause loading other files such as files from `/etc/profile.d/` but  all these additional files are explicitly loaded from main profile,  look for lines containing `source smth` or single dot: `. /etc/somefile`. You may check if /etc/environment is mentioned in `/etc/profile` of your distro.

Also you may try to run `bash --login -x` and see what commands are being executed.